# How to get missing skulls in Halo MasterChief Collection?

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection

I was looking info about why there is not all skulls available in the game, so after some research I stumbled that you had to pre-order to get bonuses, then after some time all these bonuses will be unlocked (12/12/2014). But the issue here is: how do I unlock these bonuses today (after 3-4 years)? I purchased my game from a digital download code, what do I need to do to get all the missing skulls?

I don't have them, none of the pre-order skulls are unlocked neither available, neither in Halo CE nor Halo 2, that means I don't have Boom, Bandana, Grunt Funeral, Bonded Pair, I only have Pinata skull, and yes I checked all Halo games, none of them have those skulls

Comment: I don't know much about the remastered Halo games, but are you sure for these skulls, you don't have to find them in game?

Comment: Yes, I found the skulls in game, but they don't appear in the skull selection screen